# Can and Should we commit SharedPreferences on NON UI thread, if yes how ?

Tags: android, multithreading, sharedpreferences

I am making an app and it has to save and extract data  at runtime, and sharedPrefrences is making my animations lag. so is there a way to save and retrieve data on NON-UI thread.

Or is there any problem with my method

```
    private void difficultyHandler(){
    sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.lScore),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    difficulty =  sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.difficultyController),0);
    if (times >= 1){

        long latestScore1 = sharedPref.getLong(getString(R.string.lScore1),0);
        long latestScore2 = sharedPref.getLong(getString(R.string.lScore2),0);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putLong(getString(R.string.lScore1),score);
        editor.putLong(getString(R.string.lScore2),latestScore1);


        if(latestScore1 >= 60 && latestScore2 >=60 && latestScore1 < 140 && latestScore2 <140){
            difficulty = 2;
        }else if (latestScore1 < 60 && latestScore2 < 60){
            difficulty = 1;
        }else if(latestScore1 >= 140 && latestScore2 >=140){
            difficulty = 3;
        }
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.difficultyController),difficulty);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

there is one more method like this.

is there a way to put the entire method on another thread.

basically i want to solve the problem of lagging.

Comment: ***SharedPreferences making things slow***  Really?? , first of all I want to know what type of data and how much of it you are saving in sharedPreferences, looking at your method, its not that considerable.

Comment: @nobleG I have 32 reading and writing events and am running on API 14 level Xperia E device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so is there a way to save and retrieve data on NON-UI thread.

`SharedPreferences` are cached. The first time you try accessing a given `SharedPreferences` (e.g., `getSharedPreferences()`), there will be disk I/O. You are welcome to do this work on a background thread, sometime in advance of when you need the preferences.

You can call `apply()`, rather than `commit()`, to persist changes to the `SharedPreferences` on a framework-supplied background thread.

Comment: Just to further clarify on the difference for jay, `apply()` is the same as `commit()`, in which the latter returns a boolean result.